דרך Segol or kometz under ד
In Parshas Balak (probably other places too), the word “דרך" is usually vocalized as ״דֶרֶך״; but at least once, it’s vocalized as ״דָרֶך״ with a kometz. Why?
Also, sometimes Bilaam and Balak have a Beis and sometimes a Vais. This change also happens with other names in other parshiyos. Why?

Your question, as of now, includes two sub-questions. I will answer both.
A) A Segolate is a word that ends with one unstressed Segol, such as חֶסֶד and קֹדֶשׁ.
The most common type of Segolate ends with two Segols in a row. This includes דֶרֶך, לֶחֶם, יֶרֶך, דֶגֶל, מַחְבֶרֶת, and more.
When such a Segolate is at a major break in a פסוק—that is, when it takes an אֶתנַחתָא/אַתנָח or when it’s the last word in a פסוק—the first Segol changes to a Kamatz. Thus, דֶרֶך becomes דָרֶך, and לֶחֶם becomes לָחֶם, and more.
B) There are two types of Dagesh: Dagesh Chazzaq and Dagesh Qal.
Dagesh Chazzaq indicates that a letter is geminated, i.e. that it lasts twice as long and is pronounced with a little extra force. It is not relevant to your question.
Dagesh Qal occurs only on the letters בגדכפ״ת. It gives them their “hard” pronunciation. For example, it turns Vet into Bet.
Dagesh Qal occurs on a letter only if it doesn’t come after a vowel. This is easy to understand within a word, but it’s a bit more complicated when we’re talking about the first letter of a word, like the ב in בלק. For that, the rule is as follows:
If the preceding word 1) ends in a vowel, AND 2) has a conjunctive trope sign, then the first letter of the next word doesn’t get a Dagesh Qal. In every other case, it DOES get a Dagesh Qal.
Thus, for example, in the phrase דִּבְרֵי בָלָק, Balaq’s name is pronounced with a Vet, because the previous word ends in a vowel and has a conjunctive trope.

There are some words, such as מלך, which end with two segol vowels in a row, but don’t undergo these changes at a major break

@J.W.Tanner That’s true. There are also a few exceptions to the Dagesh Qal rule (מי כמכה, כי-גאה גאה, etc.). You’ll find that literally every extant rule of pronunciation in Biblical Hebrew has its exceptions, for various historical and traditional reasons.

This is called a pausal clause as I recently learned here from kazsi bacsi, magicker72, and Double AA.

there is derech; "way", or dorech when it is an esnachta or sof passuk
In Balak, there is the word dorach; which means something else.

דָּרַ֨ךְ כּוֹכָ֜ב מִֽיַּעֲקֹ֗ב

Tehilim 119:1
אַשְׁרֵ֥י תְמִֽימֵי־דָ֑רֶךְ הַ֝הֹלְכִ֗ים בְּתוֹרַ֥ת יְהֹוָֽה׃

If it's דָ֫רֶך it means the word is in pause, meaning that the accent is a disjunctive one, so it lengthens it. Sometimes a shva become a qamets or a tsere if it's in pause

also Sheva could become other vowels, e.g. יָדֶֽךָ and תִּגְנֹ֑בוּ

It just depends what was there before

It’s more accurate to say that the vowel becomes a Shva in non-pausal form. The pausal form is older.
